# How does Drupal 7's SQL call for 'node' and retrieve an image?

Tags: 7, views, database

I have the following query shown in one of my views:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, 
node.sticky AS node_sticky, 
'node' AS field_data_field_featured_image_node_entity_type, 
'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 
'node' AS field_data_field_premium_content_node_entity_type, 
'node' AS field_data_field_article_type_node_entity_type, 
'node' AS field_data_field_video_upload_node_entity_type
    FROM 
    {node} node
    INNER JOIN {field_data_field_sports_type} field_data_field_sports_type ON node.nid = field_data_field_sports_type.entity_id AND (field_data_field_sports_type.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_sports_type.deleted = '0')
    WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('article')) AND (field_data_field_sports_type.field_sports_type_tid = '1884') ))
    ORDER BY node_sticky DESC, node_created DESC
    LIMIT 8 OFFSET 1
```

What does the `'node'` in this query return, for instance when I'm calling:

```
...'node' AS field_data_field_featured_image_node_entity_type,
```

It seems to me that this should just return the string "node" but in the preview it's actually showing the image. When I do the SQL query in the console it's just returning the string 'node'. I'm confused because I don't see any `JOIN` statements on things like the `field_featured_image` table in this query, which I would have expected if the query actually was pulling the image.

How is the image getting shown via this query?

Answer (score 0):

It's utilizing a loaded entity to fill in these placeholder columns. Per the [`views_handler_field_field::query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21field%21views_handler_field_field.inc/function/views_handler_field_field%3A%3Aquery/7.x-3.x) docs:

> By default, the only columns added to the query are entity_id and
>   entity_type. This is because other needed data is fetched by
>   entity_load(). Other columns are added only if they are used in
>   groupings, or if 'add fields to query' is specifically set to TRUE in
>   the field definition.

In the post-execute phase, during [`views_handler_field_field::post_execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21field%21views_handler_field_field.inc/function/views_handler_field_field%3A%3Apost_execute/7.x-3.x),  you can see where the field values are dropped in from the entity values.